# How to Create Values based on Start-Stop Info in Separate Column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very messy dataset created by a research device.  This data shows a physiological measure ("Physio") for every few milliseconds ("Time").  The output lists several user messages, such as when a trial starts ("START_TRIAL n"), when a trial ends ("STOP_TRIAL"), and other random things that may be of interest to the researcher. Some times the "START_TRIAL n" message is repeated consecutively, and sometimes when there is no message, a simple "0" is left in what would otherwise be a blank cell.

I am hoping to create a new column that will signify which trial the current case belongs to.  (See example data below).

Is there a way to do this with dplyr and mutate?  I am wondering if I may need to do an if-then statement that changes the values of a new column for every case, but surely there's a more elegant solution?  (Thank you in advance for helping out this newbie!)

```
Time    Physio  Cond
1   34  START_TRIAL 1
2   33  0
3   25  RANDOM_MSG
4   43  STOP_TRIAL
5   27  START_TRIAL 2
6   54  START_TRIAL 2
7   32  0
8   54  RANDOM_MSG
9   23  STOP_TRIAL

structure(list(Time = 1:9, Physio = c(34L, 33L, 25L, 43L, 27L, 
54L, 32L, 54L, 23L), Cond = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("", "0", "RANDOM_MSG", "START_TRIAL 1", 
"START_TRIAL 2", "STOP_TRIAL"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", 
"Physio", "Cond"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

into

```
Time    Physio  Trial   Cond
1   34  1   START_TRIAL 1
2   33  1   0
3   25  1   RANDOM_MSG
4   43  1   STOP_TRIAL
5   27  2   START_TRIAL 2
6   54  2   START_TRIAL 2
7   32  2   0
8   54  2   RANDOM_MSG
9   23  2   STOP_TRIAL

structure(list(Time = 1:9, Physio = c(34L, 33L, 25L, 43L, 27L, 
54L, 32L, 54L, 23L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Cond = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
"0", "RANDOM_MSG", "START_TRIAL 1", "START_TRIAL 2", "STOP_TRIAL"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", "Physio", "Trial", 
"Cond"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to identify the 'START_TRIAL' with `grep`, do a `match` to get the index and `fill` the NA elements with the previous non-NA adjacent element

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Trial = match(PhysioCond, unique(grep("START_TRIAL", 
             PhysioCond, value = TRUE)))) %>% 
   fill(Trial)
#    Time    PhysioCond Trial
#1   34 START_TRIAL 1     1
#2   33             0     1
#3   25    RANDOM_MSG     1
#4   43    STOP_TRIAL     1
#5   27 START_TRIAL 2     2
#6   54 START_TRIAL 2     2
#7   32             0     2
#8   54    RANDOM_MSG     2
#9   23    STOP_TRIAL     2
```

NOTE: Not clear about the column name, but the logic should work well

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c(34L, 33L, 25L, 43L, 27L, 54L, 32L, 54L, 
 23L), PhysioCond = c("START_TRIAL 1", "0", "RANDOM_MSG", "STOP_TRIAL", 
"START_TRIAL 2", "START_TRIAL 2", "0", "RANDOM_MSG", "STOP_TRIAL"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
  "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: @akrun I liked your answer here because you rock in your answers !!! thanks a lot